# springboot + infinispan invalidation mode : How can used with shared cache storage?

Tags: spring-boot, infinispan

I have a springboot project used infinispan to run the invalidation mode under the cluster for cache.

The questtion is about infinispan.
In fact, I read the official document: `"In invalidation, the caches on different nodes do not actually share any data"` and now I am in this situation.

I use the method a provided: `Cache.putForExternalRead(key, value)` and this method can solve the problem that when I puts the data into the cache of the Node A, the B node invalidates it, But I can't use the springboot annotations, such as @Cacheable.

I also read "Invalidation mode can be used with a shared cache store." from document but I don't know how to do this and I hope you can provide some help.

The goal I hope to achieve is that in the invalidation mode, I put a data into the cache of Node A, Node B will accept a copy data from A.Can I do this with invalidation mode ?

I try use invalidation mode with opening `CLusterLoader` but there is a risk of getting old value when node get data from other nodes.

I use replicated mode now. However, `"replication practically only performs well in small clusters(under 10 nodes)"` and `"Asynchronous replication is not recommended"`.So I just can use synchronous replication.

Which performance will be better for invalidation and synchronous replication ?

Looking forward to your help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring annotations won't fully support INVALIDATION mode unless you use a ClusterLoader. Under the hood annotations use `put`, we might consider adding a feature to support `putForExternalRead` behavior in the future, but it won't be there very soon.
Annotations work well with LOCAL, REPL and DIST modes.

```
ConfigurationBuilder b = new ConfigurationBuilder();
b.persistence()
    .addClusterLoader()
    .remoteCallTimeout(500);
```

If you are afraid about getting stale values and not being performant enough with a replicated cache, you might consider using a distributed cache.